Existence of finite blocking sets for compact group
I'm following these notes.
Let $G$ a compact group and $V$ an open neighbourhood of the identity.
$A$ is called a $V$-blocking set if $A \cap gVh \neq \emptyset$ for all $g,h \in G$.
Does always exist a finite $V$-blocking set?
My idea is to  cover G with the open sets of the type $gVh$ and extract a finite cover. So the $A=\{g_i,h_j\}$ of the finite cover is a possible blocking set. But i don't know how to prove it.

First note that if $V$ is an open neighborhood of the identity, then $GV^{-1}$ is an open cover of $G$, so there is a finite set $F$ such that $FV^{-1}=G$ by compactness of $G$. Hence $G=FV^{-1}=\{g\in G: F\cap gV\ne\emptyset\}$. This shows that with $A=F$ we have $A\cap gV\ne\emptyset$ for all $g\in G$. A similar statement holds when considering right translates of $V$.
Now for the case of both sided translates, first find an open symmetric neighborhood of the identity $U\subseteq V$ such that $U^2\subseteq V$ (let me know if you need a reference for this). Similarly as before find finite sets $F_1,F_2$ such that $F_1U=G=UF_2$. From before we know that for all $g,h\in G$ we have $F_1\cap gU\ne\emptyset$ and $F_2\cap Uh\ne\emptyset$ (note that this uses $U=U^{-1}$). Therefore
$$
\emptyset\ne (F_1\cap gU)(F_2\cap Uh)\subseteq F_1F_2\cap F_1Uh\cap gUF_2\cap gU^2h \subseteq F_1F_2\cap gVh.
$$
Letting $A=F_1F_2$ proves the assertion.

Thanks! Great answer!
